# A better way to do Cartesian Product

Tags: python

What I'm looking for is a way to do the cartesian product *n* amount of times, similar to:

```
[(i_1,...,i_n) for i_1 in range(x) ... for i_n in range(x)]
```

I am supposed to build my own function for this. I know I can do something along the lines of:

```
[...[7, 5, 6], [7, 5, 7], ...]
[...[7, 5, 6, 1], [7, 5, 7, 2], ...]
```

But, I'm looking for a more elegant solution. In fact, I would like to know if there is a way to do it like the first line of code above.

Comment: I'd use the python libraries.

Comment: @PeterWood not allowed, this is an exercise, supposed to build my own

Comment: As the `for` loops are over the same `range(x)` each time, this question is slightly different from the supposed duplicate. The solution would be [`itertools.product(range(x), repeat=n)`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.product)

Comment: @Stuart in any case, supposed to build my own function

Comment: Check the question marked as duplicate - there are several answers that don't use the libraries. A simple recursive version: `def range_product(x, n): return [()] if n == 0 else [(i, ) + t for t in range_product(x, n-1) for i in range(x)]`

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes well, you need to be specific in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use `itertools` then 1st solution below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCGzJLWoJD8/p5iroCgzr0QjJ7O4RAMuqFdQlJ9SmlyiUZSYl56qYaSpowBhGcNZJppA8P8/AA)

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.product(range(2), range(3), range(4))))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

---

Second solution without using any modules:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xDoMwDET3fIVHu2WgpRMSX4IYkLBbS1FASRa@Pk2IWtqbTvfudNseX6vrUlpYQPCiMVBvIEsFLDssAQwDtDUt2pXtAkhHwDbwiWT1wKAO8mxspxN8YJzVFl6vxls/0X/p54AbguuxMGbz6iJaDREF/eyejHdqoLru6x6UldIb)

```
def f(*its):
    if len(its) == 0:
        yield ()
    else:
        for e in its[0]:
            for tail in f(*its[1:]):
                yield (e,) + tail

print(list(f(range(2), range(3), range(4))))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: not allowed, supposed to beuild my own function

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes Updated my answer with 2nd solution manually implementing product function without any modules.